# How can I appear as online when I login to my Android app?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have made an app in which the scenario is as below: 
user can register and that registration information goes to a PHP server and is stored in a MySQL database. 
This is my PHP file:

```
 <?php

  // Check if he wants to login:
  if (!empty($_POST[username]))
  {
    require_once("connect.php");

    // Check if he has the right info.
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gen_users
    WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'
    AND password = '$_POST[password]'")
    or die ("Error - Couldn't login user.");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
    or die ("Error - Couldn't login user.");
    if (!empty($row[username])) // he got it.
    {
      echo "success";
      exit();
    }
    else // bad info.
    {
      echo "comes in else part";
      exit();
    }
  }
?>
```

If I enter a username and password that match from MySQL database, then it throws the word "success" to Android class and will go further in the app. I have a display list-view of registered people in my app.

How can I know how many people use my app right now? The people who are logged-in in app are to appear as a green image in a list view and other people are to appear as a red image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? some kind of chat client ? do you want live updates on who's online or not ?

Comment: Thank you for you time, Actually i want so show green image who are login in same time and red image who are not using my app in the same time.

Comment: and do you need it to be updated live ? i mean if you need it to change from green to red when user logout or do you need it updated only for the time the user logged in

Comment: yes, exactly. When user will logged out it will be green.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this an Android application accessing a PHP site?

Comment: This is Android -> PHP -MySql Clint-Server App. In Which use need register first. This information goes to PHP-Mysql. Then user try to login by that registered info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition to @GlaciesofPacis answer you can do one of the following:

1. send a request for the server in intervals and check who's online or not.
2. you can use a client-server mechanism - which -is much more complicated but much more efficient and elegant - and make the server push to all online clients when some client is now off or on.

i don't really know what your app is supposed to do, but option number 2 - for my opinion - worth the hard work..

links:

1. [intro to socket servers in php](http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/)
2. [intro to socket servers in java](http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html)

Comment: Yeah, my answer will help get it implemented, but yours will help keep the data current (particularly if clients randomly disconnect, time out, etc.)

Comment: can you give me any link of tutorial of any example ?

Comment: i've added 2 links for socket servers (the second option i've suggested).. i truly recommend you to use the java socket server, because java is much more powerful language especially when you need to write a fast and big server using multi-processing. although you might want to start and try using php server at the beginning because it's a bit more understandable.

Comment: if you need more help - don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a column to your users table regarding logged-in status (tinyint(1) since it's a MySQL table). It will be populated as either 0 (indicating logged out) or 1 (logged in). Upon logging in, the value needs to be set in the database as 1, and within your logout function, set back to 0. This way, you can use something similar to the below (which assumes the use of User objects):

```
<?php
$users = getUsers();
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $display = "";
    if($user->isLoggedIn())
    {
        $display .= '<img src="green.png" alt="Logged In" />';
    }
    else
    {
        $display .= '<img src="red.png" alt="Logged Out" />';
    }
    $display .= $user->getUsername().'<br />';
    echo $display;
}
?>
```

The SQL command to alter your table:

```
ALTER TABLE gen_users ADD COLUMN loggedin TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. Have any tutorial regarding to it ?

Comment: I recommend looking at Asaf's answer for the implementation of most of it. My answer is mostly for how to set it up into the database, and then how to use the column to display the result.